# Getting distance of lines between points on map using Distance matrix in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance, measurements

I created a Distance matrix from a vector layer of 36 points. I want to show all the distance lines between all the points.

In the Distance matrix layer, I click `Properties > Symbology`, then under the Symbol layer type I use `Geometry Generator`. Under Geometry type I select `LineString/MultiLineString`. Units are `Map Units`.

Finally, I use this code:

```
make_line(
    geometry(
        get_feature('Site Type 2', 'id', "InputID")
        ), 
    geometry(
        get_feature('Site Type 2', 'id', "TargetID")
        )
    )
```

When I click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, nothing happens. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should work, as long `Site Type 2` is the name of the **initial** point layer (not the Distance matrix layer). Otherwise, you can also use (a bit shorter) `get_feature_by_id`:

```
make_line (
    geometry (get_feature_by_id('Site Type 2', "InputID")),
    geometry (get_feature_by_id('Site Type 2', "TargetID"))
)
```

[image]